# springdoc-openapi in external Apache Tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, openapi

I deploy `springdoc-openapi` application to external server. I have tried but not working, when I fetch the below URL it is working fine to swagger UI

```
http://localhost:7001/application-name/swagger-ui/index.html
```

But when I seach API doc with `/v3/api-docs` getting below error

```
Fetch error undefined /v3/api-docs.
```

File `application.properties`

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
module-name=MYAPP REST SERVICE 
api-version=0.1
```

My application is based on Spring Security so defined below as public URL

```
    public static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS = 
            {   
                    "/v3/api-docs/**",
                    "/swagger-ui/**",
                    "/swagger-ui/",
                    "/swagger-ui",
    
    }
```

It is a Spring Boot microservices app that deployed on tomcat server which is working fine. Now if run Open API 3 with embed Tomcat then working fine but not working when deployed at external Apache Tomcat server.

Comment: When using an embedded Tomcat your application's context path is empty; in an external Tomcat it changes to `/application-name`, hence the URL of the documentation also changes: `http://localhost:7001/application-name/v3/api-docs`.

Comment: Thanks Poitr, So what I understood at embedded server I am using url as -http://localhost:1000/swagger-ui/index.html and the I am searching via /v3/api-docs.  Now when I am using external tomcat server I no need to use the "/swagger-ui/index.html"

Comment: Yes, that's giving entire json data. But not like that what swagger-ui provide. Still If search via "/v3/api-docs" I am getting -"errorundefined /v3/api-docs". Any Idea why I am getting this error where same code is working fine at embedded tomcat server.

Comment: **All** URI paths in the external Tomcat will have `/application-name` prepended compared to their embedded Tomcat counterparts (that's how a Tomcat server allows multiple applications to be deployed without URL conflicts). Rename the war file to `ROOT.war` if you want to have the same URLs as in the embedded Tomcat. Set `server.servlet.context-path=application-name` Spring Boot property if you want the embedded Tomcat to behave as the external one.

Comment: Thnx, that means I can't use http://ip:port/application-name/swagger-ui/index.html & then use /v3/api-docs in search box. Here my problem is only /v3/api-docs search is not working in swagger-ui,

Comment: Did you try `/application-name/v3/api-docs`?

Comment: /application-name/v3/api-docs - this is work perfectly. But swagger-ui/index.html page when I search via /v3/api-docs it is not working

Comment: I meant: did you try using `/application-name/v3/api-docs` in the search box?

Comment: Thnx, great it is working fine /application-name/v3/api-docs